# MS Excel - How do I parse a string until I reach the end?

Tags: excel

In MS Excel.

I have a string of characters that varies in length, but is always an even number of bytes long.  I need to place a comma after every two bytes until I reach the end of the string.  Once I get to the end of the string, I do not want to put a comma and I want to stop.

For example:

```
'1234567890' should turn into '12,34,56,78,90'
'12' should turn into '12'
'1234' should turn into '12,34'
```

My current 'brute force' method is to use the following formula:

```
 =MID(A1,1,2)&","&MID(A1,3,2)&","&MID(A1,5,2)&...&MID(A1,101,2)
```

But this results in a bunch of commas at the end that I then have to scrub out.  Is there a better way to write this formula so that it will automatically stop when it gets to the end of the original string?  I'm thinking there must be a way to incorporate the LEN function into this, but my skills are too limited.

Comment: This would be trivial in VBA.  Is that an option?

Answer (score 1):

Try this small **UDF**:

```
Public Function InAComma(v As Variant) As String
    Dim L As Long
    L = Len(v)
    If L = 2 Then
        InAComma = v
        Exit Function
    End If

    InAComma = ""
    For i = 1 To L Step 2
        InAComma = InAComma & "," & Mid(v, i, 2)
    Next i
    InAComma = Mid(InAComma, 2)
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=inacomma(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient application of standard functions for this does not spring to my mind, so given the formula's length I'm guessing a little more won't be an issue:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,1,2)&","&MID(A1,3,2)&","&MID(A1,5,2)...&MID(A1,101,2),1.5*LEN(A1)-1)
```